# Tokbox SIP integration with Nexmo for Conferencing

Tags: sip, opentok, tokbox

I have a question regarding the integration of Tokbox SIP gateway and Nexmo for the purpose of merging in calls into a number with the Tokbox conference. Here is the use case:

We already have Tokbox running and hosting our a/v conferences. We would like to have the ability to allow users who are not on the computer be able to dial into the phone number and be joined in the tokbox a/v conference.
At the moment we also have the nexmo part working and able to answer a phone call play a message, wait for a meeting id and and pin.

My question is how to integrate the Tokbox part to Nexmo as it pertains to the Tokbox API. Do we have to have Tokbox "dial" the SIP meeting on Nexmo or do we have to have Nemo somehow connect to the Tokbox SIP gateway?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

TokBox/Nexmo Developer Advocate here.

Yes, ideally you would dial out from an OpenTok session using SIP Interconnect to a Nexmo long virtual number(LVN) and route that incoming call to same call where the `meetingId` corresponds to the pin that the PSTN user entered.

Unfortunately, at this time, it's not possible to call the Nexmo LVN directly using OpenTok SIP Interconnect so conferencing is not possible today, but we're working on the feature so PSTN users would be able to dial in using this bridging.

Comment: Thanks, so basically I have dial into the same number using the Tokbox Dial RESET API from the server and somehow pass it the meeting ID and PIN just as a phone call user would. Does the same question apply to Twilio?

Comment: Yes, you can either use the REST API or use one of the server SDKs: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/server/

Comment: @VahidKowsari can you please share your solution here with me. I'm facing same issue.

Comment: @Manik does TokBok/Nexmo has created something for this requirement ? Any straight forward solution?

Comment: You can send the sessionId/meetingId as a part of the SIP header so that when it's forwarded from nexmo, you can look it up in your db/storage to match the associated pin for the call.